# Select rows with the lowest M values, out of N values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that's structured like so:

```
id   value  hour
1     4      176475
2     2      176475
3     3      176475
4     2      176475
1     2      184563
2     1      184563
3     4      184563
4     3      184563
...   ...    ...
1     2      N
2     3      N
3     1      N
4     4      N
```

The key property is that the data is split into hours which are in ascending order. The 'hours' are timestamps truncated to enforce 24 buckets per day. I want to do several things:

- Pull all of the rows for the first hour
- Sum `value`s for each ID over 3 hours, 8 hours...N hours.

Is there a simple way to do this? I am aware that I could use NTILE to label the data but that's a very expensive operation in Spark.

EDIT:

Expected Result for aggregating hours 1-3:

```
id     value
1        9
2        7
3        10
4        8
```

The values are made up, but the idea is to sum the values of the IDs in each of the 3 hours, so that I have one value per ID, instead of three.

Comment: Can you also add expected result? (Using your sample data.)

Comment: Sure, I've added the expected result for aggregating hours together.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) as `value`
FROM yourTableHere
WHERE hour between (NOW() - INTERVAL X HOUR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY id, hour
```

Breaking the query down.

1. Select the ID and count the `value` from yourTable.
2. Where `hour` is between X hours ago and now.
3. Group the results by `id` and `hour` between the given timestamps.

Replace X with 1/3/8 or more for the hours you wish.

Comment: Unfortunately `fromTimestamp` and `toTimestamp` are not provided. I am processing new batches of data every hour. The only concrete information I have about the timestamps is that there's 24 of them per day's worth of data. The values of the timestamps are unknown to me when I write the SQL.

Comment: In your aggregation you should start your batch from 00:00 and iterate 23 times until 23:00. Ofcourse in a timestamp. And you should store your last aggregation timestamp. If you would run it now your `lastAggregationRunTimestamp` should be 13:00 (in timestamp). So everytime when you run your aggregation command you can fetch the `lastAggregationRunTimestamp`. Does this make sense? Else could you add more context for ex: how do you process your batch and how do you run the aggregation?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. For context, I'm processing the data in Spark, by pulling 24hrs of data into Spark every hour. I want to aggregate results for the most recent hour, the most recent 3-hours, and the most recent 8-hours.